# Configure Pidgin with office proxy

Tags: windows, instant-messaging

My gtalk runs behind a proxy at office. To connect, I have to set the following:

Proxy: **IMProxy** or **171.22.218.212**

Port **8085**

Proxy requires authentication: **False**

I tried but was not able to configure **Pidgin** with my office proxy.

What are the settings required to make pidgin connect to Google via a proxy?

**GTalk**

Here is the screenshot of my gtalk Network connections settings page which works perfectly:

[image]

**Pidgin**

Basic:

[image]

Advanced:

[image]

Comment: are you asking any hacking techniques ?

Comment: No hacking whatsoever!

Comment: What protocols are you trying to use with pidgin? IRC, ICQ, etc?

Comment: jabber(XMPP) for using gtalk

Comment: all of what you have above should work.  Have you tried everything above w/ the built in Google Talk protocol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basics are from Google Answer to [**Configuring Pidgin for Google Talk**](http://www.google.com/support/talk/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=24073).
They seem fine.

Beyond that,

1. Change your **`Connect server`** to **`talk.google.com`**
   You have been told in other answers to do this,
   but your question image does not reflect that correction

   - Check connectivity through proxy with
     `telnet talk.google.com 8085`
     This should get a `Connected to` line and a `Escape character is` line usually.
     The TCP connect will happen and then get closed since TELNET will not talk `gtalk`.
     This will confirm the proxy worked to get you through to Google `talk` server.
   - Do these two tries separately to see if one of them works,
   - Keep the "`Force old SSL`" and "`Allow plain text Auth`" both **unchecked**
   - Keep them both **checked** -- to see if that works

---

**Update from comment**,
When you try `telnet talk.google.com 8080`,
TELNET connecting and getting closed is a **good** sign,
like I said, that is expected, TELNET cannot talk with the **gtalk** server.
It can only do the initial 3-way TCP handshake

- **Telnet**: Hello, this is me (SYN);
- **talk.google**: Hi there, good to see you (SYN-ACK),
- **Telnet**: Oh, you are around, lets talk (ACK)
- then, TELNET does not know the language to go further :-)

  - but, Pidgin does, and can continue from there...

If you find `8085` does not connect with TELNET and `8080` does,
**then, `8080` is very likely the correct proxy port**.
(8080 is more commonly used for proxies too).
Have you verified `8085` is declared as the proxy port in your network?

It would be very surprising to find `talk.google.com`
connect arbitrarily through port `8080` for any other reason,
while, `8085` shows a timeout.

---

**On your updated question with `gtalk` configuration**.
Something is not correct here.

1. How can your `gtalk` work for destination port `8085` when you cannot even `TELNET` to that port?

   - And, Why can you `TELNET` to `8080` (successful connection, though, it closes after that)
     but then, `Pidgin` cannot even connect?

You should probably check with `netstat`, `TCPView` or maybe `wireshark`
to see what happens to your connection attempts here.

Comment: telnet talk.google.com 8085 doesn't work i.e ,"Connecting To talk.google.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 8
085" but it works with 8080. It is getting connected and closed.

Comment: If talk.google.com responds to a connect attempt at `8080` for you, change your Pidgin configuration to that port.

Comment: When you get this working, please tell us your "`Force old SSL`" and "`Allow plain text Auth`" configuration settings -- for the record.

Answer (score 1):

Choose Proxy Type as HTTP, prover server -> enter the proxy server IP address, port, 8085 (as mentioned above)

Comment: It is not working.

Comment: Does your office have a firewall that's blocking ports?

Answer (score 1):

Try XMPP as your protocol type.

Try this:

[image]

Comment: Giving SSL connection failed error. Do I need to enter username/password. I tried entering and leaving it blank. Not working either ways. btw, do I have to set the proxy details in Preferences? I tried putting that also :'(

Comment: Username Password should be blank here as your proxy doesn't require authentication.  Try it without "Force old (port 5223)".  BTW, I'm assuming your settings on the Basic page are correct.

Comment: Actually, scratch that. The Connect port should be 443, not 423.  Leave Force old port 5223 checked.

Comment: tried all above steps. doesn't work..

"(

Answer (score 0):

Require SSL/TLS checked

Force old (port 5223) SSL unchecked

Connect port: **5222** (not 5223)

Connect server: **talk.google.com**

And use **HTTP proxy settings** or can try **Environmental settings**.

Comment: Could not establish a connection with the server:
HTTP proxy connection error 407

Comment: I could connect using proxy easily with Gtalk. Is it a problem with Pidgin?

Answer (score 0):

From what I observed, I have the same problem from my workplace too. There is also a proxy without login/password. Google Talk works, but it won't connect from Pigdin.

In my opinion, it's a matter of port. Google Talk doesn't use the same ports as the XMPP (I might say something silly, correct me if I'm wrong). From tcpview, I could see only ports like 1420, or else, being used.

Fact is, many proxies are configured to refuse tunneling on other ports than a defined list (80, 443, etc). Obviously the GTalk program manages to find a port to connect, but I think the direct connection from Pigdin is somehow refused.

In this case, I don't think he will be able to use it at work.